# Haskell: use a Mersenne twister

Tags: haskell

I need normally distributed random numbers and was thinking Mersenne twister. I tried to install the 
[mersenne-random package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random)
but that didn't work (cabal failed to install due to missing .cabal file, so I suspect the package might be broken).

Is there any other way to get a Mersenne twister in Haskell?

Comment: What did you try exactly? I'm pretty sure the package is not broken...

Comment: Maybe you ran `cabal install -fuse_sse2` as the hackage page seems to suggest? You need to specify the name of the package to install too of course.

Comment: That's exactly what I did... `cabal install -fuse_sse2 mersenne-random` seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [mersenne-random-pure64](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64) package? I was able to install it using cabal without any problems.